# Eclipse & JSF & Tomcat 6: "FacesContext not found"

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomcat, wizard

Using Eclipse Helios, I tried to start a JSF based project.

After having created a new workspace, I installed the web-tools-platform stuff. All using the "Install New Software" in the Help menu, this worked quite well.

To start developping for my project, I created a new project using the wizard, with which I downloaded and installed Tomcat 6.0 instance and runtime and configured it with the preset "JavaServer Faces v1.2 Project".

I created one single index.jsp-file (again with the wizard using the JSF-template) and put a JSF-outputText on it.

Deploy to the tomcat seems to work. When calling index.jsp in a browser, I get several times the following exception:

```
> 29.12.2010 18:24:00 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: FacesContext not found
 at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.getFacesContext(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:321)
 at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:228)
 at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(login_jsp.java:95)
 at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:69)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Every single step I did was a standard-clicking-through-wizards process.

Any idea why this doesn't seem to work?

I can easily post screenshots or file excerpts if that helps, though I don't do it here to avoid overloading the question.

---

***Edit: web.xml*** This file comes directly from eclipse, i left it unmodified except that I removed the description-tags in order to shorten the whole stuff:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Stundenplan</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Already tried setting the url-pattern to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` but then it's coming up with the exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config`

Thanks and regards, Tobias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user posted his answer some days ago was completely right (whyever the post was deleted).

It's necessary to add the jstl.jar-file to `/WEB-INF/lib` AND in eclipse, you need to **add it to the build path**

And I didn't understand that if the url-pattern is `/faces/*`, even if no such folder really needs to exist but you can call the file anyway, e.g. `/faces/index.jsp`

Thanks a lot